# Rails Routes, Have Nested Resources and Not Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

is it bad form to end up with routes that look something like this?:

```
resources :users
  resources :places

resources :places
```

Since users have many places, and there are also many places that may not be associated with a user, just curious if this is ok, will I run into route problems or db problems since places has been stated twice as a resource? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yeah that's not great. Try using `:shallow => true` to accomplish the same effect.

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :places 
end
```

http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes/

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources

Comment: does shallow still send more than one route to the same place?  e.g. will /users/1/places/1 and /places/1 both exist?

Comment: Aren't these redundant? If you have the places ID just use /places/1. If you want to see what routes are available you can always call `rake routes`

Comment: the problem with this is that you still can't see all places via /places. you know a workaround for this?